# SetActive not working in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

Learning Roll a ball project from unity project, and pickup do not remove when player collides with them. it just go through inside them like a transparent object,  here is my code.

```
void onTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Pickup")
    {
      other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure onTriggerEnter is really called!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one, maybe two problems with case sensitivity in your code.

1. the method's name is `OnTriggerEnter`, note the capital 'O'. Unity uses a case sensitive search when it looks for methods to call.
2. tags are case sensitive, too. The tutorial uses `PickUp` as tag, so make sure your code matches the tag you set in the Unity Editor.

Comment: yea i have already figured it out... but Thanks for the help :) btw tags was OKAY because i used capital "P" the problem was in "OnTriggerEnter" O is capital in this method.